# how to fetch content after first comma

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a file a.txt with content:

```
text,sometext ,\/\|
```

I want to fetch content after first comma. That is `sometext,\/|`

```bash
cat a.txt | head -1 | grep 'text' | awk -F "," '{print $2}'
```

I've tried the above command and was expecting `sometext,\/|` but instead got `sometext` as it is considering second `,` as delimiter.

Comment: How about `cat file.txt | awk -F , '{print $2}'`?

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut`:

```
echo "text,sometext ,\/\|" | cut -d',' -f2-
```

This tells `cut` to:

- use comma as a delimiter
- output the second field (f2) and all subsequent fields (-)
- it will output `sometext \/\|`

Your `awk` command prints **only** the second field.  Since you told it to split on comma, then the fields are:

1. text
2. sometext
3. /|

So it prints only sometext